# How to make $filter operator inside a projection of an aggregation using the MongoDB Scala Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala

I need to filter array of embedded documents inside a projection of an aggregation operation. I know there is this new [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator, but I do not know how to use it with the MongoDB driver for Scala. If anyone can help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an array `locations` and I want to keep in array object with field `location` where `location` string ends with "Deutschland"

In shell it look:

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        locations: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$locations",
                as: "item",
                cond: {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                        "input": "$$item.location",
                        "regex": "Deutschland$"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

in Scala:

```
collection("someCollection").
      aggregate[TypeOfObjectInArray](Seq(
    project(fields(
      computed("locations", Document ("$filter" ->
        Document("input" -> "$locations", "cond" ->
          Document("$regexMatch" -> Document("input" -> "$$this.location", "regex" -> "Deutschland$")))))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is way to do `aggregation` after using `filter`(field `i` > 0) and `project`  (convert input as `ITimes10` value after multiplying `i` with `10`) pipeline stages.

```
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Aggregates._

collection.aggregate(Seq(filter(gt("i", 0)),
  project(Document("""{ITimes10: {$multiply: ["$i", 10]}}""")))
).printResults()
```

For more details visit this github links [mongo-scala-quick-tour](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/docs/reference/content/getting-started/quick-tour.md) and [mongo-scala-aggregation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/docs/reference/content/builders/aggregation.md)